# PDO and variables php

Tags: php, variables

I would like to replace mysql connection server information with variables instead it throws an error on my side.

```
$objDb = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=mydb', 'root', '');
```

Would like it to look like this:

I have tried this but to no success;

```
$objDb = new PDO('mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db', $user, $pass);
```

Comment: Just to be perfectly sure, what is the value of $host and $db?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use double quotes:

```
$objDb = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db", $user, $pass);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$objDb = new PDO('mysql:host='.$host.';dbname='.$db, $user, $pass);
```

Or:

```
$objDb = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db", $user, $pass);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
// Usage:   $db = connectToDatabase($dbHost, $dbName, $dbUsername, $dbPassword);
// Pre:     $dbHost is the database hostname, 
//          $dbName is the name of the database itself,
//          $dbUsername is the username to access the database,
//          $dbPassword is the password for the user of the database.
// Post:    $db is an PDO connection to the database, based on the input parameters.
function connectToDatabase($dbHost, $dbName, $dbUsername, $dbPassword)
{
    try
    {
        return new PDO("mysql:host=$dbHost;dbname=$dbName;charset=utf8", $dbUsername, $dbPassword);
    }
    catch(PDOException $PDOexception)
    {
        exit("<p>An error ocurred: Can't connect to database. </p><p>More preciesly: ". $PDOexception->getMessage(). "</p>");
    }
}
```

So you could do this:

```
$host = 'localhost';
$user = 'root';
$databaseName = 'databaseName';
$pass = '';

$db = connectToDatabase($host, $databaseName, $user, $pass);
```